# PT4115 LED driver

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, led-driver

Excuse me if my question is too specific. I'm trying to get an LED driver using PT4115 work. I've spent hours but no success. I've created exactly the circuit depicted in the [datasheet](http://www.micro-bridge.com/data/CRpowtech/PT4115E.pdf).

[image]

I have used 0.33ohm resistor (0.300mA), 95uH inductor, 100uF capacitor and 1N5819 diode. I've checked all parts a hundred times. When I power the circuit with 12V DC I measure 4.3V at the DIM pin, I think this is a good sign the chip is working. But when I put a resistor as the load it seems as if th is short circuit and I get no constant current, for example with 22ohms I get 520 mA instead of expected 300 mA. I have no experience with buck convertors, what can be wrong?

Comment: 22R x 0.52A = 11.5V i.e. your load is supplied directly from the supply. This means that the switching action could not be initiated or most likely the IC is kaput. Perform a continuity test between SW and GND pins. If you see a short then we can say that the IC is broken.

Comment: Can you add a picture of your circuit? I have some suspects, but I wanna see how you made it. Also, what are you feeding to the DIM pin?

Comment: Why are you using a resistor as the load? It's designed to drive an LED.

Comment: @RohatKılıç yes it seems to be supplied directly from the supply. I replaced the IC a couple of times. SW and GND pins are not shorted (>200kOhm) additionally I measure 4.3V (however It is expected to be around 5V) when I just connect the power, it means the internal regulator is working (DIM pin is pulled up by 200kOhm internal resistor).

Comment: @VladimirCravero I made a PCB at home, it's a mess but all connections are solid and everything is OK. If you have to see it I can upload a picture tomorrow.

Comment: @JackCreasey I've already toasted several LEDs, I don't see why a resistor should not work.

Comment: You have added an RL time constant, and the chip is trying to switch at somewhere close to 1MHz. If you don't want to risk an LED, use a diode.

Comment: I suspect that cathode of the schottky diode in your circuit is connected to GND instead of Vin. This bypasses the IC and so the load is supplied directly from Vin.

Comment: OP, please do add a picture of your PCB.